Investment required for net-zero economy
I'm not sure if this it the correct forum for this question, but here it goes.
In this WEF article it states that a yearly $3 trillion investment will be needed up until 2050 for a net-zero economy.

According to the Energy Transitions Organization, about $3 trillion
will be needed to be spent on new infrastructure, as well as
generation, each year until 2050 to finance the transition to build a
totally net-zero economy.

This is the original source for that statement, this the intermediate. My question is, how did they arrive at this conclusion? Because I can't see where they got this information from; there is no mention of the year 2050 in the report and $3 trillion is only mentioned as a approximation of the total energy expenditure in 2023.
Thanks

The source is: Systemiq analysis for the ETC (2023); BloombergNEF (2022), Counting Cash in Paris Aligned Pathways – analysis based on IEA Net Zero scenario.
